# What am I doing wrong with this quadratic formula?

Tags: java, math

```
    a = 1, b = -7, c = 12

    public static void quadratic(double a, double b, double c){
    double r1;
    double r2;
    double turducken;
    turducken = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);
    r1 = (-1*b) + ((Math.sqrt(turducken))/(2*a));
    r2 = (-1*b) - ((Math.sqrt(turducken))/(2*a));

    System.out.println("r1: "+r1);
    System.out.println("r2: "+r2);
```

The System prints out 7.5 and 6.5 when the correct answers should be 4 and 3.

I cant quite figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Isn't `(-1*b)` the same as `-b`?

Comment: I'd also use `b*b` instead of `Math.pow(b,2)`.  `Math.pow` allows any `double` as the exponent, including non-integers, and is probably implemented like `Math.exp(2*Math.log(b))`, which takes a heck of a lot more computation than `b*b`.

Comment: @ajb: already suggested that below (although without any explanation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should be:

```
 r1 = ((-1*b) + Math.sqrt(turducken))/(2*a);
 r2 = ((-1*b) - Math.sqrt(turducken))/(2*a);
```

(i.e. everything divided by `2 * a`)

You could simplify your expression slightly further:

```
 double sq = Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c);
 r1 = (-b + sq)/(2*a);
 r2 = (-b - sq)/(2*a);
```

(I find the simpler the expression, the easier it is to spot mistakes)

Answer (score 2):

You've got your parentheses in the wrong place! Note: `((Math.sqrt(turducken))/(2*a))` when only `2*a` should be in the denominator.